# Plugin for multiple IntellijIdea versions using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, plugins

I am developing the plugin for intellijIdea. There is in build.gradle:

```
intellij { 
    version '2018.3' 
}
```

for example. Does exists a way to set few versions of IDE? In plugin.xml I can set

```
<idea-version since-build="182" until-build="182.*"/>
```

but it doesn't allow install plugin on another version IDE

Answer (score 2):

In `patchPluginXml { ... }` block define:

- `sinceBuild` - for the `since-build` attribute of the `<idea-version>` tag. Default value: `IntelliJIDEABuildNumber`
- `untilBuild` - for the `until-build` attribute of the `<idea-version>` tag. Default value: `IntelliJIDEABranch.*`

Also make sure you have `updateSinceUntilBuild` property in `intellij { ... }` block  set to `true` (default is `true`).

See the plugin's documentation: [Patching DSL](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/blob/master/README.md#patching-dsl).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I mean another feature. 

I have a project like http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system/prerequisites.html. Then I build it by running task build/build in Gradle panel. I get pluginName.zip file in build/distributions catalog. Then I go to Settings/Plugins in IntellijIdea and click Install from disk and select created zip. I can do it just in IDEA version I set in build.gradle file before building

Comment: I do not understand the question then. Could you reformulate the problem?

Comment: plugin.xml doesn't limit me. I can manually set since-build "181.0" and that must fit. But I ought to set intellij{ version } parameter in build.gradle. I cant set few and if I set, for example,  "2018.3", I couldn't install it on v2018.2 IDE

Comment: Alexandr Zolotov answered at jetbrains support forum. That's the feature and I ought to make separate builds for versions and put them all to a repository. Thank you for your time